# How do I see my $PATH on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been struggling with "PATH" issues while setting up Rails and other things on Mac for a long time now, and I can't get a straight answer about how I can just see my $PATH and change it. I'm just running the Terminal right now, but if I need to run another program to run Bash commands or something I can probably figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Execute the following command in Terminal to view the current value of `PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

To modify this `PATH` variable, create a `.bash_profile` file in your home directory (`/Users/username/.bash_profile`) and add a line similar to this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/directory/location
```

Comment: I tried export PATH=$PATH:/Users/tommynicholas and then echo $PATH and still have a huge mess.

Comment: Then all your executables in that directory will be available in bash. Is this not what you want? Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: OK sorry I didn't make this clear - I know that Bash is probably useful but I don't really know what Bash is, how to access it, or how it helps me find my path. What I'm trying to achieve is I'm trying to reset my Path right now, but in the future I want to be able to edit it when these problems come up again.

Comment: You get Bash when you open Terminal, so don't bother with that. Where is the file that you want to add to `PATH`?

Comment: I want to reset the PATH to what it starts out as. I'm basically just in a mess of a ton of rails apps that have done so much editing to my environment, I want to start from scratch or close to it.

Comment: What's the current value of `PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/tommynicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/Users/tommynicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/Users/tommynicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/Users/tommynicholas/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/tommynicholas:/Users/tommynicholas:/Users/tommynicholas

Comment: I see. Well, I can't tell you exactly where these paths are added, but there are three files you can check: `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and `.profile`. All these files are in your home directory (`/Users/username`). If you see a line like `export PATH=` then it modifies this `PATH` variable. RVM adds something like `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`. Check these files, clean them up, and restart Terminal.

Comment: Ok I did that, still seems to be the same. I wonder what the heck I did?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell it from here what modifies it and where. This is something you need find out. I gave you some hints, but this is all I can help.

Answer (score 3):

To see your current PATH,

```
echo $PATH
```

in a Terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

type:

```
echo $PATH
```

You can check your .bash_profile file and edit $PATH variable there. If that file does not exists then you can create a new one and you can export PATH there using:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```